# Weighted least squares with error correlation

Tags: regression

I was wondering if errors have a nonzero correlation, is weighted least squares appropriate in
this case?

Comment: Can you state the manner in which your residuals are correlated? Is this a non-stationary time-series? Do you have some structure (eg, curvature) in your residuals that you haven't accounted for?

Comment: Are the "errors" you're concerned with the theoretical random variables in the model, or the residuals in a sample regression?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can use weighted least squares when data have correlation in the errors.  For additional information with references, see the [Wikipedia article for least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Parameter_errors_and_correlation) which specifically discusses the cases of correlated verse uncorrelated experimental errors.